Function not found inside .dll created using vb6 inside vb.net 4.8.1
I'm trying to access the function inside a VB6 created dll, but it fails stating that the name of the function cannot be found. I'm trying to access the function inside vb.net using framework 4.8.1
The VB6 code for the dll is as follows:
Name of the class module: MyTest
Public Function myFunc(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sReturn As String
    sReturn = "[test]" & sInput & "[/test]"
    
    myFunc = sReturn
End Function

The VB.net code for Form1:
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Function myFunc Lib "C:\temp\Test DLL.dll" (sInput As String) As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub bTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bTest.Click
        Me.tOutput.Text = myFunc(Me.tInput.Text)
    End Sub
End Class

The error I get:
Kan ingangspunt met de naam myFunc niet vinden in DLL C:\temp\Test DLL.dll.
translation: "Cannot find entry point named myFunc in DLL C:\temp\Test DLL.dll."
I've tried to use the following command, but that did not make a change: regsrv32 C:\temp\Test DLL.dll
Here's the .dll opened in notepad, so you can see the function is there:

What code in VB.net do I have to use to access the function myFunc?

Declare Function is for calling functions that are exported from a DLL, this does not work with VB6 DLLs which are instead COM libraries.  Package your VB6 code into a class then you can call it from .Net via COM, E.g. http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_use_vb6_dll.html

@AlexK. thanks. Sounds like an answer to me. If I go this approach, do I have to do a regsvr32 on every pc that I wish to use the dll as part of my program, or is it only for development?

regsvr32 is only needed for something that will be used out-of-process.  You should be able to add a COM dll as a reference to a .NET project and it should work correctly.  You will need to be aware of bitness, as VB6 is 32-bit only so your project will also need to be 32-bit only.

@Craig thanks for that warning about 32bit vs 64bit

I got it to work.
There are a few things you need to do.
First, if you are planning on working on the DLL and make changes, if you have a DLL already, make a copy of that DLL first, and don't change it.
Next, in vb6, go to Project -> myTestDLL properties (bottom one).
From here change the following:

tab Compile, Native code, no optimization
tab Component, Version compatibility, Binary compatibility, and browse to the copy of the DLL you made earlier.

In your code, you only place the function, nothing else is needed.
I removed the following from my project file again, its not necessary (see the other answer).
[VBCompiler]
LinkSwitches=/EXPORT:myFunc

Next, I copied the dll from my vb6 development machine to my .net development machine.
There I placed the DLL somewhere where I want to use it, and opened a command prompt as administrator and ran regsvr32 
The reason we use binary compatibility is so that each time we create a new version of the DLL, it keeps the guids, and you don't need to register the DLL again.
Next, Add a reference to the DLL in .net as a COM object, and finally, the following code can be used in your project to access the function:
Public Class Form1
    Public myTestDLL As New myTestDLL.MyTest
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub bTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bTest.Click

        Me.tOutput.Text = Me.myTestDLL.myFunc(Me.tInput.Text)
    End Sub
End Class



You need to tell the compiler to export your function if you want it to be available to other programs. Edit your project file (.VBP) in Notepad and add the following lines at the end:
[VBCompiler]
LinkSwitches=/EXPORT:myFunc

Even so, you need to be aware that before calling this function from your .NET project you must instantiate a dummy object from your VB6 ActiveX DLL, otherwise it will crash:
Set objDummy = New YourActiveXDLL.DummyPublicClass


Oh, this sounds promising. I'll test it later today. :)

Okay, adding the linkswitch definitely changed the behavior. I now get an access violation. I'll now try to figure out your second line.

I think I've done it correctly, but its still throwing me an access violation error.

If you're sure you've successfully instantiated an ActiveX object before calling your function then try declaring the function parameter ByVal and use Long instead of String for testing purposes to make sure everything is working correctly. Strings are a bit trickier to pass back and forth.

I changed everything to long and byval, in both my vb6 project and the .net one. The error in .net is still the same: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that other memory is corrupt.

I can't help you with the .NET part but have you tried making your function a public method of the ActiveX class and see if it works when you call it in this way just to see if it makes a difference?

How do I do that, if I rename Public function myFunck to Public Method myFunc, it gives me an error: expect end of statement after method.

Okay, I figured it out. I did it completely different to this answer though. But thanks for your help. The +1 from me remains as a thank you for your help and patience. :)

Public functions of classes are called methods, this is just a general nomenclature common to all OOP languages. You can just instantiate an object of that specific class and then you can call its methods directly without the need to export them.
The "Public Declare Function" syntax from your original post refers to functions that reside in a BAS module, not a class module. Those need to be exported in the manner presented above.

Try cleaning and rebuilding both the project that compiles the DLL, and the solution that references the DLL. In all likelihood the project referencing the DLL isn't using the up-to-date version.

I created both from scratch as a test. There's no cleaning up to do. I must be missing an important step here to make it work. If it helps, VB6 is on a different system than VB.net

@LPChip The error is telling you that the function does not exist in the DLL. You're using the wrong version of the DLL. Clean and rebuild the DLL, and use the new version in your project.

I provided the source code, its there! I can open the .dll in a text editor and see the name for the function, its there.
